# Programatically querying Delta Table via Athena is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, databricks, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I have a delta table stored in s3 and metadata stored in Glu. I updated that table's schema by adding new column to it. I also updated the schema of that table in Glu. After all these changes I'm able to query the table via Athena UI.

Here is the query

```
select status from deletes where request_id = '1234'
```

However when I'm running the same query via AWS Golang SDK, I'm getting follwing exception

```
DELTA_LAKE_INVALID_SCHEMA: Metadata not found in transaction log for deletes
```

Here is the golang snippet that I'm using to query

```
func queryAthena(s *StorageAthena, query string) (string, error) {
    var input athena.StartQueryExecutionInput
    input.SetQueryString(query)

    var executionContext athena.QueryExecutionContext
    executionContext.SetDatabase(s.dbName)

    var resultConfig athena.ResultConfiguration
    resultConfig.SetOutputLocation(s.bucketName)

    input.SetQueryExecutionContext(&executionContext)
    input.SetResultConfiguration(&resultConfig)

    result, err := s.Db.StartQueryExecution(&input)

    if err != nil {
        log.Error("StartQueryExecution: Error executing the status query", err.Error())
        return "", err
    }

    var queryExecutionInput athena.GetQueryExecutionInput
    queryExecutionInput.SetQueryExecutionId(*result.QueryExecutionId)
    duration := time.Duration(5) * time.Second

    var queryState *athena.GetQueryExecutionOutput

    for {
        queryState, err = s.Db.GetQueryExecution(&queryExecutionInput)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("GetQueryExecution: Error executing the status query", err.Error())
            return "", err
        }

        s := *queryState.QueryExecution.Status.State
        if s != "RUNNING" && s != "QUEUED" {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(duration)
    }

    if *queryState.QueryExecution.Status.State == "SUCCEEDED" {
        var resultsInput athena.GetQueryResultsInput
        resultsInput.SetQueryExecutionId(*result.QueryExecutionId)

        rows, err := s.Db.GetQueryResults(&resultsInput)

        if err != nil {
            log.Error("GetQueryResults: Error executing the status query", err.Error())
            return "", err
        }

        resultRows := rows.ResultSet.Rows

        if len(resultRows) > 0 {
            return resultRows[0].String(), nil // Fetch first row as status query will return only 1 row.
        } else {
            return "", errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Error while fetching rows. Fetched %d rows", len(resultRows)))
        }

    } else {
        return "", errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("ExcutionId : %s, State : %s. Reason : %s", *result.QueryExecutionId, *queryState.QueryExecution.Status.State, queryState.QueryExecution.Status.AthenaError.String()))
    }

}
```

`StorageAthena` is a struct with `Athena` object and other configurations

```
type StorageAthena struct {
    Db         *athena.Athena //exported for testing
    bucketName string
    dbName     string
}
```

I've already checked that the golang service principal (which is a JSON-RPC service deployed in EKS) has access to Athena, Glu and S3.

Here is the list of permissions on Athena

```
"athena:BatchGet*",
"athena:Get*",
"athena:List*",
"athena:CancelQueryExecution",
"athena:StartQueryExecution",
```

for Glu

```
"glue:BatchGet*",
"glue:Get*",
"glue:List*",
```

for S3

```
"s3:Get*",
"s3:List*",
```

I'm unable to figure out what could be wrong causing this issue. Is there any other place where I have to update the schema/metadata for the table ?